# How to optimize SQL query? Keys are not being used

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

How can I optimize the following query? I have tried to create indexes (idx_events, idx_events_startdate, but they don't help. The query takes 10s which is far too much.

```
....
131 rows in set (10.25 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT results.event from results 
               INNER JOIN events ON results.event=events.id  
               where (DATEDIFF(NOW(), events.startdate) < 30) 
               AND (DATEDIFF(NOW(), events.startdate) > -1) 
               AND results.status='OK' 
               group by events.id;
+----+-------------+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys                                | key        | key_len | ref                   | rows   | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | results | ref    | idx_event,idx_status                         | idx_status | 53      | const                 | 773425 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | events  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_events_name,idx_events_startdate | PRIMARY    | 4       | eventor.results.event |      1 | Using where                                                         |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Instead of `datediff`, compare the dates with a pre-calculated value (passed to the query)

Comment: Start by turning around those two conditions on events.startdate. Put the column on one side, and the constants on the other. That way the engine should understand it can use an index.

Comment: For `datediff` to do its job, the way you constructed the query makes it read every possible record in the table in order to calculate the value. Therefore, what @TJ said - precalculate the date value. Don't try to "intelligently" write queries and then throw indexes at the table hoping it'll make it fast..

Comment: @TJ I'd rather calculate the date in a query like this than pass it in.

Comment: @Arth Me too. `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30`  didn't come to my mind at that instant. I was suggesting an approach to avoid the diff that leads to ignoring the index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping an indexed column in a function prevents the optimiser from using it. It looks like you need to free up the index on startdate to get a nice filtered result set for your JOIN:

```
SELECT r.event from results 
  JOIN events e
    ON e.id = r.event
   AND e.startdate > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
   AND e.startdate < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 WHERE r.status = 'OK'
```

I like placing my joined table conditions in the ON clause and using table aliases where possible.

I'd also prefer an integer status column to a string 'OK', you can foreign key this to a status table with the description if you need it.

As an added aside.. I also like to use `>=` and `<` for date ranges, if for example, `startdate` is a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, this query will exclude values for `2014-08-01 00:00:00` if it is on the cut off of `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY`.

Comment: I get an error when executing the query: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DAYS    AND e.startdate < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY  WHERE r.status = 'OK'' at line 1

Comment: Thanks! 132 rows in set (0.61 sec). That I can live with!